# Use custom attribute in a[href*="#"]

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML

```html
<a data-new-count="/new/button" href="mysite.com/folder/page/new.html">
```

Can someone please help me figure out how can I include the `data-new-count="/new/button"` custom attribute in the `a[href*="#"]` script?

`a[href*="#"]` works when I do not have the custom attribute in my HTML.

Comment: What's the `a[href*="#"] script` ? Do you want to get the value of the `data`-attribute? Do you want to use it as a selector?

Comment: I have the selector a[href*="#"] and it works when i have <a  href="mysite.com/folder/page/new.html" but when i have <a data-new-count="/new/button" href="mysite.com/folder/page/new.html" it is not working. how can i make sure it works even when i have the custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

A `a[href*="#"]` is not a script but an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Such a record means that we get all anchors `a` that contains `#` in href. You can see it in this example:

```js
[].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(element) {
 alert(element.getAttribute('data-new-count'));
});
```

```css
a[href*="#"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a data-new-count="/new/button" href="mysite.com/folder/page/new.html">link1</a>
<a data-new-count="/new/button2" href="mysite.com/#/folder/page/new.html">link2</a>
```

But if you want to get a value from custom `data-` attribute, then you can use the code in the snippet.